# mockRestore does not clear a jest.spyOn().mockImplementation mock

Tags: testing, jestjs

I am mocking `Date.now()` implementation returning a specific date however, after the test is done the `afterAll` + `mockRestore()` doesn't quite rid of the mock.

When I run another test the date now is still mocked to 1626764400000. Is there a different function I have to use to reset the mock? I have already used: `mockReset`, `mockClear`, `jest.clearAllMocks`.

```
beforeAll((): void => {
  jest.spyOn(Date, 'now').mockImplementation(() => 1626764400000);
});

afterAll((): void => {
  jest.clearAllMocks();
  jest.spyOn(Date, 'now').mockRestore();
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reset or clear a spy in Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53350382/how-to-reset-or-clear-a-spy-in-jest)

Comment: @daishin it doesn't unfortunately. I do it `afterAll` too.

Comment: 1. where did you mock Date.now? in which file? Where the another test is placed?

Comment: @AndreyNelubin same file, different `describe`

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk can you show it? Without the bodies of tests

Comment: No solution yet ? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved a similar issue by calling `mockRestore` of the returned value of the `jest.spyOn()`, that also returns a Jest mock function.
[Oficcial docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname).

Comment: This answer did not work for me. I tried:

`let spy = jest.spyOn(testFeature.Service, 'getObj').mockImplementation(() => {return 'junk';});`

 `spy.mockRestore();`

It was not restored in later tests.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `jest.restoreAllMocks()`. As the docs says

> since Jest 21.1.0 Restores all mocks back to their original value.
> Beware that jest.restoreAllMocks() only works when mock was created with **jest.spyOn**;

So your code should be like :

```
 beforeEach(() => {    
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to refactor the code like this -

```js
const mockedDateNow = jest.spyOn(Date, 'now')

beforeAll((): void => {
  mockedDateNow.mockImplementation(() => 1626764400000);
});

afterAll((): void => {
  mockedDateNow.mockReset();
  mockedDateNow.mockClear();
  mockedDateNow.mockRestore();
});
```

This worked for me. :)

Comment: Based on the Jest documentation ([mockClear](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockclear)), this should be overkill as `mockRestore()` includes the behaviour of `mockReset()` which includes the behaviour of `mockClear()`.