# Jest: Expected done to be called once, but it was called multiple times

Tags: jestjs

I recently upgraded to jest v28 from v24, installed **jest-environment-jsdom** and my configuration is   `"jest": { "testEnvironment": "jsdom", "setupFiles": [ "<rootDir>/setup.js" ] }`
I was using done `it('test', (done) => { done() })` in many places in the same test file, i am getting the error "Expected done to be called once, but it was called multiple times." when i enable multiple test cases, it works fine with single test case.

Answer (score 0):

When you use your spy/mock multiple times in different tests, they don't get reset by default after every test.

This answer should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55873465/16068019

Comment: don't think mocks have anything to do with this